# How to open a URL using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, url, guzzle

I want something similar like JavSacript's `window.open()` method, which I can use to open a particular URL, for example, https://www.google.com/.

Is there a way in pure `PHP` where I can do the same thing?

I know we can do that using selenium in python. I think `guzzle` might be of some help but I can not find anything useful on the web on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `redirect("https://www.google.com/")`;

Comment: php runs on your Server, JavaScript runs in the Clients browser, where do you want to open Google.com?

Comment: i want to open the url in clients browser @mech

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Or even `header('Location: https://www.google.com/')` as redirect is not a PHP function!

Comment: Do you need the URL to open as 1. "sort-of-popup" window, 2. Within the current page, but not as a popup 3. In another page?

Comment: i want to open the page on browser when i run the php script through terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: on serious note , it is never required in the real world problem..

Comment: @SoumiBasu : take a look about  php-gtk : http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.php

Comment: @IlyasMimouni this module seems like something similar to what i want. Thanks! :)

Comment: you should just used <a> tag if it required user interaction otherwise use header function in php if its an automatic redirect. It depends on your need.

Answer (score 6):

Although you can not open a new window through PHP directly, you can use:

```
header("Location: <LOCATION_TO_REDIRECT>");
```

To redirect the current browser window to the specified URL.

Comment: this is not a reponse, this will juste redirect and reload page. but not open new window. so -1

Comment: There is no option to open a new window through PHP :)

Answer (score 4):

`echo` JavaScript somewhere in your page, which contains code to open a new window to the desired location.

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("http://google.com");
</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why did not use simplest way:

`$page = fopen('http://www.example.com/filename.html');`
or  `$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/filename.html');`

and return like `echo $page;` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just talking about  **REDIRECTING** than there are many ways:

```
header("location:ur url");
```

OR `echo"<a href='ur url'></a>";`

OR `form submit`

OR using `JS` in php function :

```
<?php
function open_window($url){
   echo '<script>window.open ("'.$url.'", "mywindow","status=0,toolbar=0")</script>;
}';


// test:
open_window('http://www.google.com');
?>
```

PHP can make any code run... it depends on you how you use PHP.

Comment: The first option works fine for me.
Second option, href: How does that redirect? One would have to click on the link. Same for form submit.

Comment: The redirect happens automatically.